# How to change the colors within aes() in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the fill of my histogram without manually putting in the colors for each bar, however, adding `+scale_color_brewer(palette="Pastel1")` to the code does nothing.

I tried to modify just the `aes()`, however, when I delete `aes()` I lose my legend and all existing color, despite having added  `+scale_color_brewer(palette="Pastel1")`

```
library(RColorBrewer) 

ggplot(Top102018, aes(x=Country, y=Life.Ladder)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill=Country)) + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Pastel1")
```

I'd like to see the bars within the histogram in a professional color theme, currently it's very colorful.

Comment: use `scale_fill_brewer`, not `scale_color_brewer`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, provide a [mcve] including the necessary data to reproduce the issue. Thank you.